# probability of at least (n/2) + 1 out of n irrelevant events

Tags: probability

Hello I'm struggling to understand something. Let's say I have 10 questions and in each one of them I have a 70% chance of answering correctly.

The chance of answering all of them correct is 0.7 in the power of 10. However what is the chance of answering correct at least half of the questions plus 1, in this case 6 ?

Comment: Do you really mean "**exactly** $6$ out of $10$ questions correct" or do you perhaps mean "**at least** $6$ out of $10$ corrections correct"?

Comment: At least 6, sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: **irrelevant events?**  Did you mean to say _independent_ events?

Comment: Yes @DilipSarwate

Answer (score 1):

In general, your chance of answering exactly $n$ correct comes from the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  In this case it is ${10 \choose n}0.7^n0.3^{10-n}$  For at least $6$, sum over $n$ from $6$ to $10$